# error: 'subrange' is not a member of 'boost::numeric::ublas'

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to learn `boost::ublas` but am having some trouble compiling code with the `subrange` function. As usual, the boost docs don't really seem to shed light on this. Here's what I've done:

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>

void DoNothing()
{
    boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> a(1,2);
    boost::numeric::ublas::subrange(a,boost::numeric::ublas::range(0,1),boost::numeric::ublas:range(0,2));
}
```

Here's the error message I'm getting:

> test.cpp:14:5: error: ‘subrange’ is not a member of
>   ‘boost::numeric::ublas’
>        boost::numeric::ublas::subrange(a,boost::numeric::ublas::range(0,1),boost::numeric::ublas::range(0,2));
>        ^

I'm guessing I haven't included a header file that I need, but I've read through the documentation (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/operations_overview.htm) but can't see anything to suggest which header, if any, I need to add to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix_proxy.hpp>
```

Comment: @Jason what version of boost are you using?

Comment: Ah, no never mind it's working, the error changed to `no matching function for...` because I'm using the wrong types, but it seems to have found the function. Thanks :)

Comment: And apparently he needs to use `boost::numeric::ublas::subrange(a, 0,1 , 0,2);`. The function that does the same with ranges seems to be `project`.

Comment: BTW, can I ask how you found out that this is the `#include` you need? I couldn't find it in the docs...